# Reload discord bot after prefix change (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, prefix

The problem is I want to dynamically change my prefix with a command. The prefix gets updated in the json file but the only problem is that the bot needs to reload to accept the new prefix. So I need a way to make the bot read the new prefix instantly after updating it in the config.json.

JSON FILE:
`"command_prefix": "."`

UPDATE PREFIX CMD: (The command is in my core cog)

```
# PREFIX CHANGE COMMAND
    @commands.group(name="prefix", invoke_without_command=True)
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def prefix(self, ctx):
        current_prefix = get_config_file("command_prefix")

        await ctx.channel.send(f'Current prefix is: **{current_prefix}** \n If you want to change the prefix use subcommand: _set_')

    @prefix.command(name="set")
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def set(self, ctx, mode):
        mode != None

        with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
            config = json.load(f)

        config["command_prefix"] = mode

        with open('config.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(config, f, indent=4)
        
        f.close()
        
        await ctx.channel.send(f'Prefix has been changed to `{mode}`')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you first initialize a bot, it creates a prefix and uses that prefix only until you recreate the bot. If you want the bot to have a different prefix or update it, you need a callback on the `command_prefix` argument.

First create the `get_prefix` function.

```
async def get_prefix(bot, message): # you can also do it by guild with message argument
    return get_config_file("prefix_command")
```

then in the Bot instance

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix)
```

Note: These both will be in the main file where you create the bot. It will change immediately every time you update the prefix.

Comment: This is my bot instance ```bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix=get_config_file("command_prefix"),
    help_command=None,
    intents = intents,
)```

Comment: Yeah, you're currently getting the prefix instead of having a dynamic way of doing it. Replace `get_config_file("command_prefix")` with the code i showed above

Comment: So if I understood you right I need to create the function in the main file? But then I dont have the bot argument because my bot is in the core.py file

Comment: @FabianHasieber I assumed that the Bot instance was made in the main file. The function is supposed to be wherever the Bot instance is

Comment: No, that's not where you create the bot. Usually it's in `main.py`. Where did you get the token and run the bot? That's where this all should be placed

Comment: I fixed it I had to put the function in the Core class and access it in the main file with Core.get_prefix. And in the function get_prefix I was missing the keyword "message" the whole time. But now its working fine! Thank you for your help and time :D